# Unable to open new browser window to display local app image (Enyo on webOS 3.0.5)

Tags: image, browser, local, webos, enyo

I have an image link in my Enyo app's index.html, which I'd like to re-open in a new browser window on webOS 3.0.5, so I can reduce the size of the image in the app itself (with width= and height=), but allow the user to view it in the original format (with the possibility of a facility to expand it too?).

```
onLinkClick: "htmlContentLinkClick"

htmlContentLinkClick: function(inSender, inUrl){
    this.$.webView.setUrl(inUrl);
}
```

The app's link is:

```
<img src="images/lookup_cpu.png">
```

which works fine, but adding

```
<a href="images/lookup_cpu.png" target="_blank">[+]</a>
```

does not produce the image in a new browser window when clicked.

I presume this is caused by the webOS browser not accepting local files. Anyone got any suggestions to get round this problem please?

.............Phil

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the system browser won't have access to an app's directory.  You can open an additional window in your Enyo app.  You could look at https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/enyo/enyo-windows.html for info on windows.  There's other information on multi-window apps on http://developer.palm.com.  I hope that's enough to get started.